# Library that has rights of different user than executable that calls it

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, credentials

I have two users in my system:

```
username: superuser  pass:aaa //user that has many rights
username: nothing  pass:bbb //user that has minimum rights
```

I have ececutable `aaa.exe` that calls functions of library `bbb.dll`.

User `nothing` runs executabe `aaa.exe`. `ddd.dll` should access resources available only to superuser. Can `bbb.dll` login as superuser and get rights? How to implement it? What API functions I should use for this purpose?

Comment: Realistically you should use two processes

Comment: DLLs don't have security token, processes do have - particularly threads would have (through impersonation).

Answer (score 0):

If the users are entirely different, and you have the logon credentials for the superuser in a sufficiently obtuse location, you could use [LogonUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx) and [ImpersonateLoggedOnUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378612(v=vs.85).aspx) upon entry into the dll function.

This is very flaky however as the non super user would technically have access to the superuser credentials unless you were running their application in some kind of locked down sandbox.

If you are trying to invoke UAC, then the most robust solution would be to have `ddd.dll` spawn a worker exe that runs elevated. You can use `ShellExecute/Ex()` with the `lpOperation` set to `"runas"` to force elevation.  If the exe is manifested, you can set `lpOperation` to NULL or `"open"` instead and let UAC prompt normally as needed. Either way, this will invoke the system's own elevation GUI that will prompt the user to either escalate their own account, or choose a different administrator (Superuser) account to complete their action.

Comment: Another option is to implement the DLL itself as a COM object and then the EXE can use the [COM Elevation Moniker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679687.aspx) to instantiate the DLL object in a different user context with UAC prompt when needed. No need to spawn a separate process.

Comment: I see you have edited my reply to reference calling CreateProcess. I am pretty sure that CreateProcess does NOT trigger the UAC GUI - it just returns an error code. ShellExecute must be used to trigger elevation prompts.

Comment: You are right, I forgot about that.  It has been awhile since I had to deal with UAC elevation issues.